# Filter result using alias

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this

```
SELECT 
    Type = TXL.Descript, Jurisdiction = CASE WHEN TX.State = 'KD' THEN 'FD' 
    WHEN TX.County > '' AND TX.County IS NOT NULL THEN 'Local' ELSE 'Country' END,
    State = CASE WHEN TX.State = 'FD' OR (TX.County > '' AND TX.County IS NOT NULL) THEN '' ELSE (select top 1 istIntlStateDesc from IntStateM ISM where ISM.istIntlStateCode = TX.MtcState) END,
    Local = CASE WHEN TX.County > '' AND TX.County IS NOT NULL THEN TX.MtcCounty ELSE '' END,
    TaxCode = TX.TaxCode, TaxDescription = TX.TaxCodeDesc, EffectiveDate = ET.EtxEffectiveDate,
    Taxable = ''
FROM 
    ETaX ET WITH (NOLOCK) 
    INNER JOIN TxCast TX on ET.Code = TX.TaxCode 
    INNER JOIN TxLMast TXL on TXL.TCode = TX.Tax
WHERE 
    ET.TDate <= GETDATE() 
    AND ET.SDate > GETDATE()
```

In the UI I have a table and I want to filer each column by passing the column name and what my code is doing is adding an **AND** condition to the **WHERE** clause while filtering but if I am passing the alias name (Ex. Jurisdiction) I am getting an error like - **Invalid column name 'Jurisdiction'**, I also can't pass the actual column name as I am using case statement in the query, for example alias **Jurisdiction** value is coming by combing 2 column name so, is there any way it will work even passing the alias name or any better way to do it like dynamic SQL or any other workaround?

Comment: If you use = sign then it compares the two column and returns Boolean except for case

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Remove the other tag.)

Comment: Aliases don't work that way - `Select x.y  AS myAliasedColumn From MyTable AS x` would be valid; at least, in SQL Server

Comment: Check out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: `top 1 istIntlStateDesc`?!? Doesn't it matter which value you get?

Comment: Please make sure to specify one and only one DBMS. Please add the tag back of the database system you're actually using.

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to filter by your "aliased" fields. To do so, you have 2 options:

1. Use subquery writing a SELECT FROM your entire query and then filtering by Jurisdiction:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT 
    Type = TXL.Descript, Jurisdiction = CASE WHEN TX.State = 'KD' THEN 'FD' 
    WHEN TX.County > '' AND TX.County IS NOT NULL THEN 'Local' ELSE 'Country' END,
    State = CASE WHEN TX.State = 'FD' OR (TX.County > '' AND TX.County IS NOT NULL) THEN '' ELSE (select top 1 istIntlStateDesc from IntStateM ISM where ISM.istIntlStateCode = TX.MtcState) END,
    Local = CASE WHEN TX.County > '' AND TX.County IS NOT NULL THEN TX.MtcCounty ELSE '' END,
    TaxCode = TX.TaxCode, TaxDescription = TX.TaxCodeDesc, EffectiveDate = ET.EtxEffectiveDate,
    Taxable = ''
FROM 
    ETaX ET WITH (NOLOCK) 
    INNER JOIN TxCast TX on ET.Code = TX.TaxCode 
    INNER JOIN TxLMast TXL on TXL.TCode = TX.Tax
WHERE 
    ET.TDate <= GETDATE() 
    AND ET.SDate > GETDATE()) AS AUX_QUERY
    WHERE
    Jurisdiction = -your condition here-
```

(Note now Jurisdiction is a result field from AUX_QUERY)

2. Repeat the full `CASE WHEN TX.State = 'KD' THEN 'FD' WHEN TX.County > '' AND TX.County IS NOT NULL THEN 'Local' ELSE 'Country' END` that you called Jurisdiction in the `WHERE` clause (or wherever you want to use those calculated fields:

```
    SELECT 
            Type = TXL.Descript, Jurisdiction = CASE WHEN TX.State = 'KD' THEN 'FD' 
            WHEN TX.County > '' AND TX.County IS NOT NULL THEN 'Local' ELSE 'Country' END,
            State = CASE WHEN TX.State = 'FD' OR (TX.County > '' AND TX.County IS NOT NULL) THEN '' ELSE (select top 1 istIntlStateDesc from IntStateM ISM where ISM.istIntlStateCode = TX.MtcState) END,
            Local = CASE WHEN TX.County > '' AND TX.County IS NOT NULL THEN TX.MtcCounty ELSE '' END,
            TaxCode = TX.TaxCode, TaxDescription = TX.TaxCodeDesc, EffectiveDate = ET.EtxEffectiveDate,
            Taxable = ''
        FROM 
            ETaX ET WITH (NOLOCK) 
            INNER JOIN TxCast TX on ET.Code = TX.TaxCode 
            INNER JOIN TxLMast TXL on TXL.TCode = TX.Tax
        WHERE 
            ET.TDate <= GETDATE() 
            AND ET.SDate > GETDATE()) AS AUX_QUERY
            AND
            CASE WHEN TX.State = 'KD' THEN 'FD' 
            WHEN TX.County > '' AND TX.County IS NOT NULL THEN 'Local' ELSE 'Country' END = -your condition here-
```

Comment: can you please be more specific

Comment: I'll read your edited question and try to :)

Comment: Done, can you check if it suits you now?

Comment: Thanks so much it worked with a little tweak in sql server, will let you if it worked after testing it from the app

Answer (score 0):

Aliases cannot be used like that, look at this example

```
declare @table1 table (id int, text1 varchar(50), text2 varchar(50))
insert into @table1 values (1, 'one', 'two')

select t1.id,
       fullname = t1.text1 + ' ' + t1.text2
from   @table1 t1
where  fullname = 'one two'
```

This will throw this exception

> Invalid column name 'fullname'

The most simple solution (imho) is this

```
select t.id,
       t.fullname
from   ( select t1.id,
                fullname = t1.text1 + ' ' + t1.text2
         from   @table1 t1
       ) t
where  t.fullname = 'one two'
```

This allows the database to fully evaluate the aliased columns, and therefore it will known them so you can use the aliased columns just like other columns